# How can I add split sources to CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm not exactly sure what the terminology for this is, but how can I add multiple folders for different possible sources of one set of headers? What I'm trying to do is add a build option for different hardware devices for a hardware abstraction layer, but the way I've implemented doesn't seem to work with smart options in IDEs.

This is the current way I've implemented the CMakeLists.txt for the HAL:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${BUILD_TARGET})
file(GLOB SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.hpp
                  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${BUILD_TARGET}/*.*pp)

add_library(tortilla SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

and the relevant line for the root CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(BUILD_TARGET "SDL" CACHE STRING "Device you are building for")
```

Also, this is the directory structure:

```
tortilla
--headers
----display.hpp
--SDL
----display.cpp
--N0100
----display.cpp
--N0110
----display.cpp
```

Comment: You probably should not use `file(GLOB ...`

Comment: Describe "doesn't seem to work". How does it not work? What doesn't work? Why do you think that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was. For smart code completion, I needed to manually modify the line that sets BUILD_TARGET and reset the CMake cache.